Issues Reading a File when Using unittest in Python
I am unit testing a credit card validating program that accepts a .txt file containing fake credit cards numbers, and returns a dictionary of the card, whether it's a valid credit card number, and the card type (visa, mastercard, etc.).
Using the unittest module, I've successfully established that my implementation of the Luhn algorithm is sound, and that the program can correctly identify the card type, using a collection of card numbers hard-coded into the test file. However, when trying to read the .txt file into the program, testing that it returns the correct results, it outputs None instead.
Is this some quirk of the unittest module, where it cannot compare function output, when the function itself read files?
Also, the .txt file is in the same shared folder as the function's file, and the test file.
Process file function
def process_file(file_path):
    try:
        with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
            card_numbers = file.readlines()
            
        results = {}
        
        for card_number in card_numbers:
            is_valid = check_card_number(card_number)
            card_type = get_card_type(card_number)
            
            results[card_number] = (is_valid, card_type)
            
        return results
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error reading file: {e}")

def check_card_number(card_number):
    if not card_number.isdigit():
        return False
        
    return luhn_algorithm(card_number)

def get_card_type(card_number):
    patterns = {
        'Visa': r"^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$",
        'MasterCard': r"^5[1-5][0-9]{14}$",
        'American Express': r"^3[47][0-9]{13}$",
        'Discover': r"^6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{12}$",
        'JCB': r"^(?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11}$",
        'Diners Club': r"^3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}$",
        'Maestro': r"^(5018|5020|5038|56|57|58|6304|6759|676[1-3])\d{8,15}$"
    }
    
    for type, pattern in patterns.items():
        if re.match(pattern, card_number):
            return type
            
    return 'Unknown'

def luhn_algorithm(card_number:str) -> bool:
    payload = [int(d) for d in card_number[:-1]]
    
    even, odd = payload[-1::-2], payload[-2::-2]
    
    total = sum(odd) + sum([(i * 2) - 9 if i >= 5 else i * 2 for i in even])
    
    return 10 - (total % 10) == int(card_number[-1])

Test Process File Function
class TestProcessFile(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_validate_card_and_get_type(self):
        file_path = r'file_path\test_cards.txt'
        
        credit_cards = ('6390448951544', '3507088898930091')
        correct_card_types = ('Unknown', 'JCB')
        correct_validation = (False, True)
        correct_results = dict(zip(credit_cards, zip(correct_validation, correct_card_types)))
        
        self.assertEqual(process_file(file_path), correct_results)

When running the program itself, it reads the file and generate the expected output just fine. But when testing the program with unittest, within the assertEqual method, the function outputs None instead of the expected dictionary.

Can you reduce this program to a [mre]? As you said, most of the functions are already working fine; your problem will be much clearer if you can minimize the amount of code in your question.

@AndrewYim, the program provided has been minimally reduced while being reproducible. The input .txt file is simply numbers (meant to simulate credit card numbers, but can be any numbers, really), each of which is on a new line.

Potential dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55695776/file-not-found-python-unit-test?

That may potentially be the case, @AndrewYim. That being said, the test file, main program files, and .txt file are all in the same folder, sharing a directory. So I'm a bit doubtful of this. But I will look into it. Thank you

@Camocarrot Are you sure that when you execute test_validate_card_and_get_type() the variable file_path contains the right path to the file test_cards.txt? I have tested your code in my system and the execution of process_file() raise (obviously) the Exception Error reading file: so it returns None...

I have executed your code in my system with 2 changes.
I have added the following import in the file process.py:
import re

I have create the text file test_cards.txt in the same folder of process.py, with the following content:
6390448951544
3507088898930091

In the same folder I have created the test file:
from process import process_file

import unittest

class TestProcessFile(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_validate_card_and_get_type(self):
        #file_path = r'file_path\test_cards.txt'
        file_path = r'./test_cards.txt'

        credit_cards = ('6390448951544\n', '3507088898930091')
        correct_card_types = ('Unknown', 'JCB')
        correct_validation = (False, True)
        correct_results = dict(zip(credit_cards, zip(correct_validation, correct_card_types)))

        self.assertEqual(process_file(file_path), correct_results)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()


Previous test file is identical to your file but with the second of my changes: the definition of credit_cards variable has the following modification (on my opinion not important and linked to the fact that I'm using a Linux system while I think you are using a Windows system):
# I HAVE ADDED THE char '\n' in the first credit card number
credit_cards = ('6390448951544\n', '3507088898930091')

In my system the execution of test_process.py gives the following successfully output (process_file() not return None):
> python test_process.py
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK


Thank you very much for your help, @User051209. Changing the file path to r".\test_cards_test.txt" in the test file did the trick for me.

The reason is that you have not defined "check_card_number" and "get_card_type" functions. Therefore, your testsuite returns None because the execution is incomplete. Try to define these two functions and the results should match then. An example:
def check_card_number(n):
  return True
def get_card_type(c):
  "x"


Hi, thank you for your response.
As to your suggestion, the two functions have been defined, but they were excluded from my explanation, as testing these two functions already proved successful.

Since actually running the main.py file outputs the expected results, I am certain that the process_file functions works. I'm just struggling to demonstrate this using unittest
